problem with "fixedProfile" boundary type for reading from a csv file in openFOAM
I have boundary values for inlet boundary my case (these values are predicted with NN a code). the values are tabulated and have been prepared in csv file formant. As I know based on searching the forums the " fixedProfile" boundary type might a good solution for me. but I do not know how to use it properly. I have a csv file for U and p but after running OF warns me: "Table read from "u.csv" is empty".
this is what I've written in U dictionary for the desired value:
       type            fixedProfile;
       profile         tableFile;
       profileCoeffs
       {
            file                "u.csv";
            format              csv;
            nHeaderLine         0;
            refColumn           0;
            componentColumns    (1 0 0);
            separator           "";
            mergeSeparators     no;
            outOfBounds         clamp;
            interpolationScheme linear;
       }
        direction        (0 -1 0);
        origin           0;

the main question is what is that what should be the structure of the csv file? should it include coordinates (x , y)?
